# Does Aptana Studio 3 support Caller Hierarchy?

Tags: aptana

I used the RadRails version 2.0 from Aptana. Now I have upgraded to Studio version 3.0 but I am unable to find the "Open Caller Hierarchy" button. It is not available in the drop down on right click nor in the main menus. Does anybody know if this action still exist or it is not currently available?

I am talking specifically for Ruby code here.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Nope, not yet available. Create a feature request at http://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/APSTUD

Cheers,
Max

Comment: Thanks I have created new request: http://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/APSTUD-3243